# Windows 7, Python 3.6.0, can't make a new file due to "PermissionError".

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7

So I used this code:

```
test_file = open('c:\\test.txt', 'w')
test_file.write('TEST')
test_file.close()
```

And it returned this error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\test.txt'

What was supposed to happen was that it would make a txt file, write TEST in it, and that's it.

Googling the error has returned no results. (that I could understand at any rate) I am quite new to programming and such, so please give me a simple answer (if possible).

Comment: you're trying to open a directory as a file, which may fail.

Comment: You don't have permissions create a file in `c:\\`. Create it in your user folder.

Comment: Thank you Klaus, that  worked perfectly!

Comment: Write access for files in the root directory of the system drive is protected by a mandatory access control label that requires a high integrity level. If UAC is enabled, even a member of the administrators group is logged on at a medium integrity level. You have to elevate to get write access. However, this doesn't apply to creating directories. You should be able to execute `os.mkdir('C:\\test')` and create files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
#you don't have permission to write to the root folder in C drive. You can try to write to your desktop
test_file = open(os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop","test.txt"), 'w')
test_file.write('TEST')
test_file.close()
#Now check your desktop you should see the test.txt file
```

Comment: That should be `home_path = os.environ["HOMEDRIVE"] + os.environ["HOMEPATH"]`. However, nowadays it's more common to use `os.environ["USERPROFILE"]`. You can get this more directly via `os.path.expanduser('~\\Dekstop')`. In any case, this assumes the user's "Desktop" folder hasn't been relocated to another directory or another drive entirely. Most per-user known folders can be moved easily using the folder properties dialog.